# What is the right way to start multiple Node instances on a multi core server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, cluster-computing

I have a Node.js app that I want to run on a multi core (2CPU * 2Cores = 4Cores) server. After reading through a bunch of Stack Overflow threads on this topic, I have decided to start 4 separate node instances on 4 different ports and use Nginx to load balance among them. I decided to use this approach over node cluster.

Here are my questions that I'm trying to answer:

1. Is there any difference in how one would start 4 node instances on a 2cpu * 2cores/cpu = 4 core server vs. 1cpu * 4cores/cpu = 4core server. I don't think there is any difference, but just wanted to confirm.
2. I have a conf file to start my service. This conf file is actually a script that resides in `/etc/init` and starts my Node app. Should I start the 4 instances from this 1 conf file or should I create 4 conf file and start one instance per conf file?

   Again, I feel the latter approach is better, but wanted to confirm it.

Comment: For vertical scaling -> Proper way is documented: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1 instance per core is a good rule of thumb, but if you also run some services on the same server (database, redis, memcache, queue, ...), you may want start less instances so these don't "fight" for the cpu.
2. You eventually going to need to restart individual instances because one crashed, or is using too much memory, or what not.  So separate scripts would be preferable, or even a script that allow you to control instances separately or together (which is more work initially).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I think you answered my 2nd question, but I am still unsure about answer to my 1st question. Are you saying that there is no difference in how I would start 4 instances on a 2cpu*2core server vs 1cpu*4cores server?

Comment: yes, I don't think there is any difference.  The OS scheduler will take care of spreading the load among the available cores.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you decided to:

1. use nginx to load balance? haproxy is a better solution for this purpose.
2. manually start n processes when there's a cluster module that does that for you?

   If you start n different processes you'll need to listen to n different ports.

   If you use the cluster module you don't need any load balancer because this job is done internally and the n workers will listen to the same port. If a worker dies you get a notification and basically you can manage them easily.

All the workers can open/read/write/close the same file, you don't need n config files.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your answer. As I had mentioned in my question, I am aware of the cluster module, but doing some research, decided to go with starting n mode instances listening on n ports. I will look in to HAProxy though.